# .NET app not starting when axMsRdpClient is used

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms, rdp

Any .NET application I make in Visual Studio won't start after publishing if it has the COM component: Microsoft RDP Client Control in it. No error messages are shown, just a loading cursor for 2 seconds and that's it. It shows the following error in Event Viewer:

> Toepassing: tesform.exe
>
> Framework-versie: v4.0.30319
>
> Beschrijving: het proces is beëindigd als gevolg van een onverwerkte
>   uitzondering.

translation: the process was terminated due to an unhandled exception

> Uitzonderingsinformatie: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>
> bij tesform.Form1.InitializeComponent()
>
> bij tesform.Form1..ctor()
>
> bij tesform.Program.Main()

And that's it, it runs fine in debugging mode. And it's not just this PC, i've tried it on several computers and servers in our network but no gain and multiple new projects to test it... Does anyone have any idea what this could be? As soon as I remove the RDP Client from the form it runs without issues.

[COM component: Microsoft RDP Client Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Y8P.png)

Comment: Describe exactly what files you deploy.

Comment: Could you explain? I'm not sure I understand..